# Extracting data from different worksheets and transfer to master report

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Guys I'm stuck with my code(the array part if not working).I would appreciate a help.

I have 6 worksheets(JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN and Reports).JAN-JUN worksheets contain employees absences records.

I need to transfer the records from worksheets JAN-JUN(employees name are not in proper order) paste in master worksheets called "Report"(all name are in ascending order)

In report I have the following header(JAN ,FEB ,MAR .......JUN ) in cells B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1.

Range("I") in each worksheets contains total absences by employees for a given month.

Range("H") in each worksheets contain employees who absent for the month.
I need to transfer only Range("I") from each worksheet and paste based on the the relevant months and employees.

My code contains an array of cell B1 to G1 from master worksheets.

```
Sub transferABS1()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim myname As String
    Dim arRng() As Variant
    Dim iRw As Integer
    Dim iCol As Integer

    arRng = Sheets("Reports").Range("B1:G1")
    For iRw = 1 To UBound(arRng, 1)
        For iCol = 1 To UBound(arRng, 2)
            lastrow1 = Sheets(arRng).Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To lastrow1
                myname = Sheets(arRng).Cells(i, "H").Value
                Sheets("Reports").Activate
                lastrow2 = Sheets("Reports").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                For j = 2 To lastrow2
                    If Sheets("Reports").Cells(j, "A").Value = myname Then
                    Sheets(arRng).Activate
                    Sheets(arRng).Range(Cells(i, "I")).Copy
                    Sheets("Reports").Activate
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(j, iCol).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                    End If
                Next j
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Next i
        Next iCol
    Next iRw
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be much easier if you just created a starter table that had headers of Name/Month/Hours. From there you could run a pivot table, or variety of analysis.

To get in a table format is easier than your two dimensional Name by Month format. This code will list all values on your Report sheet.

```
Sub listAllNamesMonthsAndAmounts()
Const theMonths As String = "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,"
Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, g As Long, aCell As Range

g = 1
ReDim eList(1 To 3, 1 To g) As Variant
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(1, theMonths, ws.Name & ",", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        For Each aCell In Intersect(ws.Range("H:H"), ws.UsedRange)
            If aCell <> "" Then
                ReDim Preserve eList(1 To 3, 1 To g)
                eList(1, g) = ws.Name
                eList(2, g) = aCell.Value
                eList(3, g) = aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                g = g + 1
            End If
        Next aCell
    End If
Next ws

Sheets("Report").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(eList, 2), UBound(eList)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(eList)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but the output is not what desired is rather transposing the data....

Comment: Yes, but you could transform it using a pivot table which would probably be a more effecient method than doing some crazy array formula or summation.

Comment: Thanks been able to do it without pivot table.